# Html.Partial in Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a simple `PartialView` setup in my MVC3 Project using the Razor View Engine.
The `Partial` will render but if I set a breakpoint in the controller on the `Action` for the `Partial`, it never gets hit. If I change the URL to go directly to the `PartialView`, i.e. http://localhost:13965/Home/GridControl, then the breakpoint is hit. What am I missing?

My view:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.Partial("GridControl",  Model)
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult GridControl()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Html.Partial` doesn't call a controller action. It is a simple include of a partial view at the place you called it.

If you want to call the controller action you need to use the [Html.Action or Html.RenderAction helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) like this:

```
@Html.Action("GridControl")
```

or:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GridControl");}
```

And obviously in this case you are not passing any model as your controller action doesn't expect any model as argument and it is its responsibility to fetch a model and pass it to the partial view that will be rendered and included at the place where you called this helper.